# How can I change html code of a page from another page?

Tags: javascript, html, data-transfer

At page index.htm, I have this list:

```
<ul id="topic">
<li id="1">Thing1.</li>
<li id="2">Thing2.</li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to add and remove li itens from other page (painel.htm):

At page painel.htm I'll have a input-text where the user writes the li container (thing1, 2, 3...) and a button to add or remove (currently in javascript-jquery).

I'd like to know the process that gives the information from the painel to the index.

At last case, I can make these pages asp using c#.

Comment: are they connected via frame/iframe/opener?

Comment: You have to change them  permenantly?

Comment: You might want to store whatever HTML you want displayed in the local storage and each time the page loads, you load that section of the page from local storage and when you need to change the html, you also update the local storage. Not ideal because not every browser handles html5 but it'll work for 95%+ of users. But really, this is something that should be handled server side IMO, not on the client.

Comment: they arent connected yet.
i dont know how to connect

Comment: and tha change isn't permanent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Generate navs through js!

<script>
/* 2 pages nav or define your own */
var pages = [ [ {id:'1',title:'Thing1'} , {id:'2',title:'Thing2'} ] , 
              [ {id:'3',title:'Thing3'} , {id:'4',title:'Thing4'} ]
            ];

/* set current page through asp.net or php like currentPage =0 for index.html and currentPage =1 for painel.htm */

var currentPage = 0;
function renderNavs()
{
     var data = pages[currentPage];
     for(var i=0; i<data.length ; i++)
     {
          $('#topic').append('<li id="'+data[i].id+'">' + data[i].title + '</li>');
');
     }
}

$('#topic').empty();
renderNavs();
</script>
```

Comment: im trying understand and apply, if i have any doubts i ask :)
but thank you since now =D